# Databind a 0 or 1 Value to CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I am using SQLDataSource bound to a data grid, how do I extend the check box control to read the value the query is passing and checking or unchecking the box because of that?

I have tried this:

```
public class CheckboxYN : System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox
{

    public string YesNo
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Checked)
                return "1";
            else
                return "0";
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == "1")
                this.Checked = true;
            else
                this.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't find the control in the ASP.NET, but I get errors in the HTML.

Comment: What are the errors you get? Normally, databinding a bit field to an ASP.Net checkbox will translate the to checking/unchecking properly without you having to do anything. How are you doing the binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to override the CheckBox class, just bind the Checked property to your DataSource's bit column:

```
<asp:CheckBox Checked='<%# Eval("BitColumnName") %>' />
```